# unable to use two gestures simultaneously

Tags: android, libgdx, multitouch

I have a class implementing gesture listener in libgdx. I want to use longpress gesture in one half of the screen and fling gesture in other part of the screen simultaneously.

public class FlingHandler implements GestureDetector.GestureListener{

```
GameWorld world;
Bmw bmw;
private float  w,h,xunit, yunit;
private float spd = 1;
private float xtouch = 0, ytouch = 0;
private float xVel = 0, yVel = 0;
private int p = 0;


public FlingHandler(GameWorld world) {
    this.world = world;
    w = SS.WIDTH;
    h = SS.HEIGHT;
    xunit = SS.x;
    yunit = SS.y;
    bmw = world.getBmw();

}
public void update(float delta){
    updateLongpress(delta);
}

public void updateLongpress(float delta){

    if(longPress(xtouch,ytouch)==true && world.getBmw().isDead()==false) {
        if(spd <1600 && Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            spd += 0.9f*delta;
            Gdx.app.log("speed ","increasing"+spd);
        }
    }

    else if(longPress(xtouch,ytouch)==false && world.getBmw().isDead()==false){

            if(spd > 1 ){
                spd -= 8f*delta;
                Gdx.app.log("speed ","decreasing"+spd);
            }
    }
    else{

    }
}

@Override
public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    xVel = velocityX;
    yVel = velocityY;
    xtouch=Gdx.input.getX();
    ytouch=Gdx.input.getY();
    p = button;

    if(xtouch > SS.WIDTH/2 && world.getBmw().isDead()==false) {
        if (Math.abs(xVel) > Math.abs(yVel)) {
            if (xVel > 0) {
                if (world.getBmw().getPosition().x < 8 * xunit) {
                    world.getBmw().getPosition().x += 4 * xunit;
                }
            } else if (xVel < 0) {

                if (world.getBmw().getPosition().x > 7 * xunit) {
                    world.getBmw().getPosition().x -= 4 * xunit;
                }

            } else {}

        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
    xtouch = Gdx.input.getX();
    ytouch = Gdx.input.getY();

    if(xtouch < SS.WIDTH/2 && world.getBmw().isDead()==false){
        return true;
    }
    else if (xtouch > SS.WIDTH/2){
        return false;
    }
    else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What's going wrong? How are you capturing the touch events?
Can you show any of the code?

Comment: i have tried this thing so far. Both fling and Longpress are working perfectly fine. But they are not working simultaneously. I need both gestures to work together.

Answer (score 2):

The `GestureListener` is something that should be passed to a detector, and the detector (which is an `InputListener`) will read touch events and amalgamate them into higher order events such as pan, fling or long press.

So I would expect your code to have something like this somewhere;
    `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new FlingHandler()));`

Since the `GestureDetector` is the one capturing the events and forwarding them to your `FlingHandler` it doesn't really make any sense to do things like this;

```
if(longPress(xtouch,ytouch)==true && world.getBmw().isDead()==false) {
  if(spd <1600 && Gdx.input.isTouched()){
    spd += 0.9f*delta;
    Gdx.app.log("speed ","increasing"+spd);
  }
}
```

You don't call longPress, the `GestureDetector` does that for you when a long press has been detected, you override the method to take action when it has happened. Also, galling `Gdx.input.isTouched()` is also weird, as you expect complete gestures to be delivered to your gesture listener.

As for detecting the gestures simultaneous; that might be a bit difficult with the `GestureDetector`/`GestureListener` as they will report events based on individual touches for *down*, *tap*, *fling* and *pan stop*, but not for *long press*. Because of this you'll probably have to hook in at GestureDetector level rather than `GestureListener` (or possibly a combination of both).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new FlingHandler())); in my code. Everthing is working great except simultaneously. Is there any other way to get this done except using Gesture Listener? My main issue is to make it work simultaneously.

Comment: The other way would be, as I suggested, to hook in at `GestureDetector` level, that way you can distinguish between touches for all events, including up and down.